# Is the firmware of intel skylake, GuC 6.1 correctly installed?

Tags: intel-graphics, firmware

the output of

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_guc_load_statu
```

is:

```
GuC firmware status:
    path: (null)
    fetch: NONE
    load: NONE
    version wanted: 6.1
    version found: 0.0
    header: offset is 0; size = 0
    uCode: offset is 0; size = 0
    RSA: offset is 0; size = 0

GuC status 0x00000001:
    Bootrom status = 0x0
    uKernel status = 0x0
    MIA Core status = 0x0

Scratch registers:
     0:     0x0
     1:     0x0
     2:     0x0
     3:     0x0
     4:     0x0
     5:     0x0
     6:     0x0
     7:     0x0
     8:     0x0
     9:     0x0
    10:     0x0
    11:     0x0
    12:     0x0
    13:     0x0
    14:     0x0
    15:     0x0
```

and the output of:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_guc_info
```

is

```
GuC total action count: 0
GuC action failure count: 0
GuC last action command: 0x0
GuC last action status: 0x0
GuC last action error code: 0

GuC submissions:
    render ring             :          0, last seqno 0x00000000
    blitter ring            :          0, last seqno 0x00000000
    bsd ring                :          0, last seqno 0x00000000
    video enhancement ring  :          0, last seqno 0x00000000
    Total: 0

GuC execbuf client @           (null):
    Priority 0, GuC ctx index: 0, PD offset 0x0
    Doorbell id 0, offset: 0x0, cookie 0x0
    WQ size 0, offset: 0x0, tail 0
    Failed to queue: 0
    Failed doorbell: 0
    Last submission result: 0
    Submissions: 0 render ring
    Submissions: 0 blitter ring
    Submissions: 0 bsd ring
    Submissions: 0 video enhancement ring
    Total: 0o cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_guc_info is:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what loaded firmware looks like on my side after adding `i915.enable_guc_loading=2 i915.enable_guc_submission=2` in grub:

```
"   GuC firmware status:
    path: i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin
    fetch: SUCCESS
    load: SUCCESS
    version wanted: 6.1
    version found: 6.1
    header: offset is 0; size = 128
    uCode: offset is 128; size = 128640
    RSA: offset is 128768; size = 256

GuC status 0x800300ec:
    Bootrom status = 0x76
    uKernel status = 0x0
    MIA Core status = 0x3

Scratch registers:
     0:     0xf0000000
     1:     0x0
     2:     0x0
     3:     0x5f5e100
     4:     0x600
     5:     0x0
     6:     0x0
     7:     0x8
     8:     0x3
     9:     0x433200
    10:     0x0
    11:     0x0
    12:     0x0
    13:     0x0
    14:     0x0
    15:     0x0"
```

DMESG (dmesg | grep guc):

`"[0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/@/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-41-generic root=UUID=d29f4f91-4a71-40f9-a086-3f2c3d401f58 ro rootflags=subvol=@ verbose i915.enable_guc_loading=2 i915.enable_guc_submission=2 intel_iommu=on
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/@/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-41-generic root=UUID=d29f4f91-4a71-40f9-a086-3f2c3d401f58 ro rootflags=subvol=@ verbose i915.enable_guc_loading=2 i915.enable_guc_submission=2 intel_iommu=on
[    5.907468] Setting dangerous option enable_guc_loading - tainting kernel
[    5.940511] Setting dangerous option enable_guc_submission - tainting kernel"`

More info and source for the fix: 
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97978
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97077

Comment: Thanks!, I edited this line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_guc_loading=2 i915.enab    le_guc_submission=2" and it is still not working :/

Comment: Of course I updated grub and so on, even I reinstalled the firmware. Any idea?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Even I reconfigured the image following https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93871, and it is still not working :(

Comment: Ok, did you install the guc module first? Download it from Intel website and run the installer reboot and try this again.

Comment: Yes, of course, actually I reinstalled it after modifying the grub. Maybe it is a bug, I don't have anymore the warning after updating the system. I don't know why the status is still with a missing version.

Comment: My dmesg after enabling the options edited. Add yours in the question field.

Comment: lines of dmesg containing guc are:   [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=98857228-6f4a-446f-a190-e038c54cdac9 ro quiet splash i915.enable_guc_loading=2 i915.enable_guc_submission=2 vt.handoff=7. That seems that only show the edited grub isn't?

Comment: Apparently you are running Linux kernel 4.4, you need 4.6+ kernel for the mcu detection. You should have "Setting dangerous option enable_guc_loading - tainting kernel" in your dmesg after adding the parameters.